# How to call an ApiController from another .net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an Asp.net Mvc3 project and I have made a ApiController in it. Now I want to call the api in a windows application project. And I dont know how to config Global.asax or web.config file to approach this. And I dont know what would be the service reference url(If the ApiController name is Service and the method in it is UpdatePrice)?

Comment: you have to call it with url: yourDomain.com/Service/UpdatePrice

Comment: You mean I should make a http wen request to do this? I want to use it like a web api service.

Comment: yes make a http request. web api is just a rest service which should be accessed over http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an **HTTP** request from the application to the **WEBAPI** action URL you want to access using `HttpClient`. WEBAPI is a REST based HTTP service, so you can access it only via HTTP unlike WCF on this context.

You can refer [**here**](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) for more information and code samples on this.